# jQuery .width() and css('width') returning invalid values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the width of a parent from an element. To do this I'm using:

```
parent = $("#"+id).parent().attr("id");
parentWidth = $('#'+parent).width();
```

I've also tried:

```
parentWidth = $('#'+parent).css('width');
```

At first I used

```
$('#'+id).parent().width();
```

this didnt work either.

The parent variable is correctly set, however, the width of a parents div is 90%, .width() returns 90, and .css('width') returns 90px. In my .css widht is set to 90%, i also tried adding it in the style tag in the element itself.

```
<div id="tabs" style="height:90%;width:90%;">
```

in the CSS file:

```
#tabs{
height:90%;
width:90%;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

I keep getting 90 as return value. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

This is the page I'm talking about: http://www.amsterdamslyceum.lelie.demodomein.com/index.php
Don't mind the db errors, didnt set up the db on the host yet as I just started developing.

Comment: You can set "parent" with `$('#' + id).parent();` and there's no need to find it by id like that.

Comment: If the parent element of your `#tabs` div has a `100px` width, it would be legitimate for `width()` and `css()` to return `90px`. Are you sure that isn't the case?

Comment: #tabs actually is the parent, it almost covers the entire webpage (90%) so the width values in CSS seem fine to me

Comment: why you dont just use document.getElementById(id).parentNode.offsetWidth; or document.getElementById(id).parentNode.style.width

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YZ3P3/

Comment: document.getElementById(id).parentNode.offsetWidth returns 0, document.getElementById(id).parentNode.style.width returns 90%. I need a pixel value.

Answer (score 3):

`$('#'.id).parent().width();`
must be
`$('#' + id).parent().width();`

do you check the parent? first in the browse console (FF and Chrome) check if this code returns the parent that you want
`$('#' + id).parent();`

Comment: the parent's id is returned fine, if you visit the link you'll see I placed alerts printing the parent div name and its dimensions. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

At first I used

```
$('#'.id).parent().width();
```

The `$("#".id)` might be your problem. Try `$("#" + id).parent().width()`

Other thought: Might `#tabs` have additional style info in the CSS?

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, I used a plus symbol, typo in the first post, i'll correct it now, thanks.

Comment: What about the css itself? Anything for #tabs?

Comment: #tabs{
 height:90%;
 width:90%;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10;
 overflow:hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

The documentation http://api.jquery.com/ready/ says this:

> When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties,
>   it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style
>   elements before referencing the scripts.

Your scripts seem to be placed before the stylesheets. I'm guessing the styles have not been loaded when your code runs.

Comment: does placing the function call in $("#tabs").ready() work? Because I had already thought of that, it didnt work for me though, but maybe I messed up somewhere.

Comment: I don't know. Try using `load` or just move the linked scripts below the stylesheets.

Comment: actually the function is called after the stylesheet is loaded, I'll try the load() function in a second, need to reboot my laptop.

Comment: Well I'm sure this is related to the problem. Wait for the page to load then run `objDimensions('tabs-1',2,2,50,0)` in the console and it works. May also be that it hasn't finished tabifying `#tabs`.

Comment: thank you @Tetaxa , should've thought of debugging like that.

Answer (score 0):

for example i try this :
`$('#tabs-1').parent().width()`

and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

try putting your script on a

`$(document).ready(function () {YOUR CODE HERE});`

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and I found out that it's because of other jQuery plugins or functions that you might be using to modify the html structure (like using sliders or tabs etc.)